# Parsing XML using Python minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

```
 <PacketHeader>   
     <HeaderField>
        <name>number</name>
        <dataType>int</dataType>
     </HeaderField>
 </PacketHeader>
```

This is my small XML file and I want to extract out the text which is within the name tag.

Here is my code snippet:-

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

xmldoc = minidom.parse('sample.xml')
packetHeader = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PacketHeader")
headerField = packetHeader.getElementsByTagName("HeaderField")
for field in headerField:
    getFieldName = field.getElementsByTagName("name")
    print getFieldName
```

But I am getting the location but not the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

xmldoc = minidom.parse('sample.xml')

# find the name element, if found return a list, get the first element
name_element = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]

# this will be a text node that contains the actual text
text_node = name_element.childNodes[0]

# get text
print text_node.data
```

Please check this.

**Update**

BTW i suggest you **ElementTree**, Below is the code snippet using ElementTree which is doing samething as the above minidom code

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")

# the tree root is the toplevel `PacketHeader` element
print tree.findtext("HeaderField/name")
```

Answer (score 0):

A small variant of the accepted and correct answer above is:

```
from xml.dom import minidom


xmldoc = minidom.parse('fichier.xml')
name_element = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
print name_element.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

This simply uses `nodeValue` instead of its alias `data`